# Namespace issue/ conflict, why?

Tags: namespaces, c#-4.0

I am introducing a new namespace called Ebot.Mind for the class Cat

```
namespace Ebot.Mind
{
  class Cat
  {
  }
}
```

Now I've a one using namespace called Mind.Logging,

```
namespace Ebot.Mind
{
 using Mind.Logging;
  class Cat
  {
  }
}
```

Now when I am trying to use any functionality under Mind.Logging namespace, it is not able to find it.

I've never dealt with such problem.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: It is possible that VS is getting confused with the Mind being common to Ebot.Mind and Mind.Logging. You could try using an alias for Mind.Logging. using mindLogAlias = Mind.Logging. That might help VS resolve it better!!

Comment: tried but did not worked! You might want to see this with vs2010 as it is fair design.

Answer (score 0):

Is Mind.Loggin located in a separate assembly? If yes you'd need to add a reference to that assembly.

As InSane points out you could also try setting an alias on Mind.Logging if there is a problem with some confusion with Ebot.Mind and Mind.Logging.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler is trying to find the namespace "Mind.Logging" under the namespace "Ebot.Mind" and so he can't find it.

To fix it, try to put "using Mind.Logging;" above the namespace declaration like this :

```
using Mind.Logging;
namespace Ebot.Mind
{
...
}
```